# change value in 1 table based on value in different table

Tags: mysql

I'm not totally clear how to ask this question, but I want to set all the poeple in a group to also be in a new group.

I want to do this...

```
mysql> UPDATE  `cla-constituents`.`person_custom` SET  `c3` =  '6' WHERE `person_per`.`per_cls_id` =7;
```

but I get "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'person_per.per_cls_id' in 'where clause'"

`cla-constituents` is the DB, `person_custom` is table 1, `c3` is the target cell

I want to change that cell for all people who have a 7 in the `per_cls_id` column on the `person_per` table. Same DB.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You haven't joined the two tables in your `UPDATE` so it has no idea what `person_per` is. Can you post your table structure for each table?

Comment: In future, don't use characters in names that *force* programmers to quote them, like ten minus sign in `cla-constituents`. An underscore would have been a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LEFT or INNER JOIN

```
UPDATE  `cla-constituents`.`person_custom` 
INNER JOIN person_per ON cla-constituents.id = person_per.id
SET  `c3` =  '6' 
WHERE `person_per`.`per_cls_id` =7;
```

Here i have joined with an imaginary column. You can use your correct one.

Comment: Why a left join instead of inner join?